# How do I setup fallback on Swift Mailer framework in php

Tags: php, swiftmailer

How do I set fallback, for swift mailer, and test my fallback code is working?.
I got this standart code from the howto.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT, 'tls')
->setUsername(SMTP_USERNAME)
->setPassword(SMTP_PASSWORD)
;

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('S5_Dagsrapport_' . $dato1)
->setFrom(array($from => 'S5'))
->setTo(array($to => $navn))
->setBody($body, 'text/html')
->addPart($body, 'text/html')
->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($attachment, 's5_dagsreport_' . $dato1 . '.xls',          'application/xls'))
;
// Send the message
$mailer->send($message);
```

if i use

```
if(
$mailer->send($message)){
echo "Sent\n";
}else{
echo "Failed\n";
}
```

it shows sent, but if I put wrong info , into the parameters, it does not show Failed.
I have been reading that another solution is to use

```
Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport
```

but I can't find examples online, on that.

what is the easy way to make a fallback in Swift_mailer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell from the class `Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport` extends.

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/LoadBalancedTransport.php

Contains a method called `setTransports`.  In there you can set the transports to use when one fails.  It is a bit like a chain class.  The class itself is an instance of `Swift_Transport` which contains multiple other transports.

Create the transports you are going to use to connect to mail servers.  Then add them to an instance of `Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport`.  Then use that instance as your mailer transport.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who wants to know how to use this in symfony here is my solution. Create a class which extends `Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport`.

```
namespace AppBundle\Util;

class App_Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport extends \Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport
{
    /**
     * @param \Swift_Mailer[] $mailers
     */
    public function __construct(array $mailers)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        /** @var \Swift_Mailer $mailer */
        foreach ($mailers as $mailer) {
            $this->_transports[] = $mailer->getTransport();
        }
    }
}
```

In your `config.yml` under the `swiftmailer` key extend your mailers:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer:       default
    mailers:
        default:
            transport: 'app_failover'
        # example mailhog config 
        main:   
            disable_delivery: false
            delivery_addresses: null
            transport: smtp
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 1025
            username: null
            password: null
        # example for sendgrid 
        fallback:
            disable_delivery: false
            delivery_addresses: null
            encryption: 'ssl'
            transport: 'smtp'
            host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
            port: '465'
            username: 'apikey'
            password: 'mypassword'
```

And last but not least inject your defined mailers in your `App_Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport` constructor:

```
swiftmailer.mailer.transport.app_failover:
    class: AppBundle\Util\App_Swift_Transport_FailoverTransport
    arguments:
        $mailers: ['@swiftmailer.mailer.main', '@swiftmailer.mailer.fallback']
```